# How to Access Openstack on my local machine from External network?

Tags: networking, cloud, openstack, openstack-neutron

I deployed a private cloud in openstack with the help of packstack, Everything is working fine, I can create new instances, Launch it, use it to install software from internet and delete it, All the set up is running on my Local machine as virtual machine in vmware, I created a router, a public and a private network. I can access Internet from my instance as well as from my main server. Basically everything is working as expected. But I can only access my cloud from the network in which I am using it.
I want to Access my horizon dashboard and my instance from an external network, how can I do this? currently I can only access my cloud from ip as http://10.0.5.2/dashboard but I want to assign a public ip to my cloud.

Comment: I am afraid this is more of a [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) question.

Answer (score 2):

From the dashboard/horizon " http://10.0.5.2/dashboard " link it means you are using the NAT/NAT network/any other internal network IP for OpenStack setup. So you can't access it outside the VMware VM.

If you need to access the horizon from outside VMware:

1. Create two interfaces in VM, one with `NAT` and other with `Host-Only networking`
2. Use the `NAT` IP for internet and `Host-Only networking IP` as `HOST_IP` for openstack setup.
3. Install the openstack and then you will have horizon link as **http://Host-only_network_IP/dashboard**
4. Then you can able to access the openstack from outside of VMware VM

Comment: Thank you kvmahesh for your suggestion,
 By "outside of VMware VM" you mean outside the network also?If you meant to say that i could access the dashboard  from other devices outside the VM,i can already do that,i can access my dashboard from my windows laptop which is connected to same network,i want to do the same when i am not in the same network as of my openstack VM.

Comment: @kumarshivam Were you able to figure out how to access it from outside the network? I'm looking to make API calls to  OpenStack installed on my local machine from an outside service.